# Security problems when trying to open a chm via the System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp in a MEF

Tags: c#, wpf, activex, mef, chm

I am attempting to open a CHM to a specific topic using the System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp method in C#. When a call this method from a WPF application or a C# command line exe the help file opens without incident. However, when I make the same call from inside an MEF visual studio extension the CHM opens with activeX and scripting disabled which causes my help file to open incorrectly.

How can I open the help file with scripting enabled and without security problems when calling this class from an MEF? Is there a way to enable scripting and activeX when opening the help file? Typically when a user opens the chm from the desktop they do not have this problem.

Thanks in advance for all your help,
Dirk7589